# Enable FTP disable SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, shell, ftp

I would like to know how to enable FTP access while disabling SSH access for all users except root and admin.

I tried to change the shell : `/usr/sbin/nologin`, but this is no good because disabling both and `/bin/bash` enable both. I also check `/etc/shell/sshd_config` and put `AllowUsers root admin` and then restart the ssh,  but that didn't solve the problem.

The server runs on Debian.

Has anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure sshd is using /etc/shell/sshd_config as it's config file?  I don't use Debian, so I don't know the path for the config file on that distro, but I can confirm that your syntax for AllowUsers is correct -- I use that all the time.

Comment: Try the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` instead.

Comment: It works fine ow thank you guys :), sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method but for shell I use /bin/false. That disabled both ssh and ftp. But add /bin/false to /etc/shells and it works. The ftp fails with that /bin/false shell because it is not found in /etc/shells

I also use vsftpd and add this
chroot_local_user=YES to /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf so that ftp-ers can't see date other then their own.